# How to have anonymous users edit Survey 123 data in a form

Tags: arcgis-online, editing, feature-service, arcgis-survey123

I have a Survey 123 form where users enter the status of a project, then they submit it. Then they need to, at the conclusion of the project, head back to the record and edit it. This editing would include changing the drop-down to closed, entering notes etc.

These are anonymous users, not AGOL accounts. If you have an AGOL account then you can log into Survey 123, head to the survey and in the data tab, voilà there you go you have the form when you click on the record. Is there anyway to accomplish for non AGOL users?

So far, my workarounds include creating a link to the feature service of the Survey 123 form in ArcGIS Classic Web Viewer. Doing this allows them to click on one of the entries and then they can edit it, but it's not the prettiest process and it's cumbersome for non-GIS users.

Essentially, I'd like if they could head back to the same Survey 123 form, with it populated with the existing records information and then they click submit and the record is updated.

Is this possible?

Comment: An aside from your question - your workflow would allow your users to modify records they may not own. Or someone who happens upon your service could modify all the values. Are you ok with that? (assuming you're allowing anonymous edits....)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of anyway to re-load a previously submitted, anonymous survey, for further edits.

One possible solution, based on your idea of having them take the feature service URL and go into an ArcGIS Online map --

- Have a field in your survey that would allow your users to tie the survey to themselves. Whether that be a "name" field, or ask them to provide a number. Either way, you just need to hope its unique, or semi-unique.
- Create a web app builder application with your feature layer in it. Add the editor widget.
- You provide the URL to the Web App, and use [URL Parameters](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/web-appbuilder/manage-apps/app-url-parameters.htm) to filter/query the data based on the unique field they submitted with their survey. This would focus the data to either a single survey, or if they used a "semi-unique" identifier, then they'd only see a few records.
- You'd need to determine the best way to get them the full URL with parameters. I'm not sure if you could construct and inform the survey submitter of the full URL to the app + params after the survey submit. Note that you CANNOT get the ObjectID/GUID of the survey. This is created on survey submit, and there is no talk back from the survey to the submitter to get that. (I highlight that as that *would have* provided a direct way to the survey)

Of course, this [workflow would be pretty straight forward](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/survey123/browser/get-answers/editexistingdata.htm) if your users were identified, as the system has all the hooks to go back to a submitted survey by user.

Comment: You solved it! In your link at the bottom, if you scroll to the bottom **Edit in Web App** if you add the following: `?mode=edit&globalId={GLOBALID}`, then it does exactly what I was hoping! Hallelujah, thanks!

Comment: That works for an anonymous survey? Cool!

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in an ArcGIS Dashboard.
Add the embedded Survey123, the web map, and a pick list to a dashboard.
Link the Pick List to the map and Survey123 via the GlobalID.

Here is how to link them.
In the Embed widget, use a URL structure to define the Survey123 o be embedded, and to pass the GloablID at the same time.

[https://survey123.arcgis.com/share/YOURCONTENTID?mode=edit&globalId={GlobalID}&hide=footer,navbar](https://survey123.arcgis.com/share/YOURCONTENTID?mode=edit&globalId=%7BGlobalID%7D&hide=footer,navbar)

Once you do this, when you select a record from the map or the Pick List, the Survey123 will refresh to the corresponding record.